# Language of app web is not taken from the user settings

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, multilingual

I am currently developing a multi-language SharePoint hosted app and I am experiencing an issue that the app web is not taking the user's language settings. It looks like the app web always takes the default language of the hostweb at creation time, i.e. when the app is added to the hostweb.

How I can enforce the appweb taking the user's language setting?

I.e. the hostweb being default en-US (1033) and having support for nl-nl (1043), the user setting being nl-nl, the hostweb rendering nl-nl (as expected; as it takes the user setting), but the app-web currently rendering en-US whereas one would expect nl-nl as per the user setting.

Comment: zie: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130206/why-does-get-title-called-from-an-sponline-app-web-return-an-incorrect-loca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the app web is provisioned just like yet another sub web. I.e. it only gets the primary language enabled by default. So after the app has been installed to your site, you need to go to the mui-settings page: `<appweb>/_layouts/15/muisetng.aspx` and activate your secondary language. After activation SharePoint works as expected: it picks up the user's language setting and renders the list fields in the appropriate language.

I also checked if we can provision this setting while the app is being installed through some CSOM API. I see some progress on the completion of the CSOM API with regards to the MUI features here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/03/20/office365-multilingual-content-types-site-columns-and-site-other-elements.aspx
Unfortunately this is not yet available for on-premise customers. You will need to apply the controversial http post pattern ;-) Cf. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2013/11/04/ftc-to-cam-advance-http-remote-operations-for-sp2013.aspx